# Use h2o.grid fine tune gbm model weight column issue

Tags: r, grid, h2o

I am using h2o.grid hyperparameter search function to fine tune gbm model. h2o gbm allows add a weight column to specify the weight of each observation. However when I tried to add that in h2o.grid, it always error out saying illegal argument/missing value, even though the weight volume is populated. 
Any one has similar experience? Thanks

Hyper-parameter: max_depth, 20
[2017-04-12 13:10:05] failure_details: Illegal argument(s) for GBM model: depth_grid_model_11.  Details: ERRR on field: _weights_columns: Weights cannot have missing values.
ERRR on field: _weights_columns: Weights cannot have missing values.

============================

```
hyper_params = list( max_depth = c(4,6,8,12,16,20) ) ##faster for larger datasets

grid <- h2o.grid(
  ## hyper parameters
  hyper_params = hyper_params,

  ## full Cartesian hyper-parameter search
  search_criteria = list(strategy = "Cartesian"),  ## default is Cartesian

  ## which algorithm to run
  algorithm="gbm",

  ## identifier for the grid, to later retrieve it
  grid_id="depth_grid",

  ## standard model parameters
  x = X,  #predictors, 
  y = Y,  #response, 
  training_frame = datadev, #train, 
  validation_frame = dataval, #valid,
    **weights_column = "Adj_Bias_correction",**

  ## more trees is better if the learning rate is small enough 
  ## here, use "more than enough" trees - we have early stopping
  ntrees = 10000,                                                            

  ## smaller learning rate is better
  ## since we have learning_rate_annealing, we can afford to start with a bigger learning rate
  learn_rate = 0.05,                                                         

  ## learning rate annealing: learning_rate shrinks by 1% after every tree 
  ## (use 1.00 to disable, but then lower the learning_rate)
  learn_rate_annealing = 0.99,                                               

  ## sample 80% of rows per tree
  sample_rate = 0.8,                                                       

  ## sample 80% of columns per split
  col_sample_rate = 0.8, 

  ## fix a random number generator seed for reproducibility
  seed = 1234,                                                             

  ## early stopping once the validation AUC doesn't improve by at least 0.01% for 5 consecutive scoring events
  stopping_rounds = 5,   stopping_tolerance = 1e-4,   stopping_metric = "AUC", 

  ## score every 10 trees to make early stopping reproducible (it depends on the scoring interval)
  score_tree_interval = 10                                                
)

## by default, display the grid search results sorted by increasing logloss (since this is a classification task)
grid
```

Comment: does your weights_column have missing values in it? did you specify a column in your dataset as the weights_column or did you create the weights_column

Comment: Lauren: Thanks for the suggestion. I went back and double checked the weights_column. It does have 4 rows with missing values. I concatenated the files in HDFS, somehow the system automatically generated rows with missing value.

Comment: gbm <- h2o.gbm(x = predictors, y = response, training_frame = train, stopping_metric = "auc")                                                                                                 "stopping_metric" must be in "AUTO", "deviance", "logloss", "MSE", "AUC", 
  "lift_top_group", "r2", "misclassification", "mean_per_class_error", but got yada

Comment: I see h2o model performance metric contains AUC, logloss etc There is one model performance metric called lift_top_group, is it lift on top decile?                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 Also can user specify the band for h2o to output gains chart such as top 5%, 5%-10%, 10%-15% ....... in h2o.gainsLift(gbm)?   Thanks!

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404805/h2o-model-performance-metric-and-gains-chart-customization

Comment: @Eric_IL were you able to fix your issue after removing the missing values?