# Why are there only 16 rows in the H2O Gains/Lift table? How should they be interpreted?

Tags: r, h2o

The latest H2O documentation states that "The data is divided into groups by quantile thresholds of the response probability. Note that the default number of groups is 20; if there are fewer than 20 unique probability values, then the number of groups is reduced to the number of unique quantile thresholds." http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/flow.html#interpreting-the-gains-lift-chart

However, in reality, only 16 rows are generated, even when there are more than 20 unique probability values in the input data, and it is unclear how they should be interpreted.

You can see this even in this example code which is taken directly from the h2o.gainsLift() help page:

```
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
prosPath <- system.file("extdata", "prostate.csv", package="h2o")
hex <- h2o.uploadFile(prosPath)
hex[,2] <- as.factor(hex[,2])
model <- h2o.gbm(x = 3:9, y = 2, distribution = "bernoulli",
                                 training_frame = hex, validation_frame = hex, nfolds=3)
h2o.gainsLift(model)              ## extract training metrics. Note that there are only 16 rows in the Gains/Lift Table.
h2o.gainsLift(model, valid=TRUE)  ## extract validation metrics (here: the same)
h2o.gainsLift(model, xval =TRUE)  ## extract cross-validation metrics
h2o.gainsLift(model, newdata=hex) ## score on new data (here: the same)
# Generating a ModelMetrics object
perf <- h2o.performance(model, hex)
h2o.gainsLift(perf)               ## extract from existing metrics object. Note that there are still only 16 rows in the Gains/Lift Table.

# There are 380 unique predicted probability values, which is greater than 20. 
length(unique(as.data.frame(h2o.predict(model, hex))$p1))
```

Furthermore, I am inclined to think that these rows do not represent 16 evenly-binned quantiles, given that the "sanity checks" for gains/lift displayed on this page include uneven bins: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-r/tests/testdir_jira/runit_pubdev_2372_gainLift.R

See line 36 on that page, in which I believe the bins are defined. They are shown as:
probs = c(0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,0.96,0.97,0.98,0.99)

How am I to understand what is being displayed on the Gains/Lift table? Can I customize the n-tile bins being displayed? I would prefer to see 10 bins, ideally.

Thank you.

Comment: reposting a partial solution to your question: "You can't change the quantiles without touching Java code, but deciles and twentiles are contained in the current table - basically there's more information than what you seem to ask for. Look at the cumulative data fractions." which was shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404805/h2o-model-performance-metric-and-gains-chart-customization/43405169#43405169

Comment: another potential workaround for getting only 10 bins can be found here:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/h2ostream/lift|sort:date/h2ostream/TCu-11rp7zc/vv1Sv-FDAQAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation should say 16 groups not 20 (originally the default was 20 groups but has since been updated), I've made a jira ticket for the issue that you can follow: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5709?filter=-2.

You can't change the quantiles without touching the Java code, but you can subset on the cumulative data fractions (look at the cumuluative_data_fraction column) that you are interested in (the gains lift table gives you more information than you may need).